# three hundred dollars bail -- shouldn't it be "three hundred dollar bail" without an "s"?

Tags: grammar, plural-forms, possessives

[Link to the Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOWpgn0tTVw) (it's right at the beginning of the video when the reporter says that)

Transcript:

> James Rhein is out on *three hundred dollar**s** bail* after being charged with criminal mischief. He tells me he doesn’t think this is that big of a deal. And he adds that his wife is "fine with it."

Why does she say *three hundred dollar bail* with an "s" on the end of *dollar*? Isn't that grammatically wrong? We don't say, for example, *he is a five years old boy*; we say, *he is a five year old boy*. What is really going on here grammatically?
I, actually, was told that many Americans do say *three hundred dollars bail*, but no explanation was offered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s possessive as well as plural. Properly, it should be transcribed like this:

> James Rhein is out on three hundred dollar**s’** bail.

If the bail was only one dollar, you’d say:

> James Rhein is out on one dollar**’s** bail.

The possessives are equivalent to these formulations with **of**:

> James Rhein is out on bail of three hundred dollars.
>
> James Rhein is out on bail of one dollar.

Comment: Phew, the cookie monster had me puzzled there!

Answer (score 2):

The reporter was saying it in a possessive sense, meaning it is "**three hundred dollars' bail**" as opposed to "**three hundred dollars bail**."
This works in the same way as "**five years' time**."